# Why Can't I Access My Kubernetes Cluster Using the minikube IP?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have some questions regarding my minikube cluster, specifically why there needs to be a tunnel, what the tunnel means actually, and where the port numbers come from.

### Background

I'm obviously a total kubernetes beginner...and don't have a ton of networking experience.

Ok. I have the following docker image which I pushed to docker hub. It's a hello express app that just prints out "Hello world" at the `/` route.

DockerFile:

```
FROM node:lts-slim
RUN mkdir /code
COPY package*.json server.js /code/
WORKDIR /code
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000 
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I have the following pod spec:

web-pod.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: web-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: kahunacohen/hello-kube:latest
      ports:
      - containerPort: 3000
```

The following service:

web-service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: web-pod
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
```

And the following deployment:

web-deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-pod
      service: web-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-pod
        service: web-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: kahunacohen/hello-kube:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
```

All the objects are up and running and look good after I create them with kubectl.

I do this:

```
$ kubectl get services                                                                            
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          7h5m
web-service   NodePort    10.104.15.61   <none>        8080:32177/TCP   25m
```

4. Then, as per a book I'm reading if I do:

```
$ curl $(minikube ip):8080 # or :32177, # or :3000
```

I get no response.

I found when I do this, however I can access the app by going to `http://127.0.0.1:52650/`:

```
$ minikube service web-service
|-----------|-------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |    NAME     | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | web-service | http/8080   | http://192.168.49.2:32177 |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Starting tunnel for service web-service.
|-----------|-------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |    NAME     | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | web-service |             | http://127.0.0.1:52472 |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|------------------------|
```

### Questions

1. what this "tunnel" is and why we need it?
2. what the targetPort is for (8080)?
3. What this line means when I do `kubectl get services`:

```
web-service   NodePort 10.104.15.61   <none>        8080:32177/TCP   25m
```

Specifically, what is that port mapping means and where `32177` comes from?

4. Is there some kind of problem with simply mapping the internal port to the same port number externally, e.g. 3000:3000? If so, do we specifically have to provide this mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me answer on all your questions.

0 - There's no need to create pods separately (unless it's something to test), this should be done by creating deployments (or statefulsets, depends on the app and needs) which will create a `replicaset` which will be responsible for keeping right amount of pods in operational conditions. (you can get familiar with [deployments in kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

---

1 - [Tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/) is used to expose the service from inside of VM where minikube is running to the host machine's network. Works with `LoadBalancer` service type. Please refer to [access applications in minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/).

1.1 - Reason why the application is not accessible on the `localhost:NodePort` is NodePort is exposed within VM where `minikube` is running, not on your local machine.

You can find minikube VM's IP by running `minikube IP` and then `curl %GIVEN_IP:NodePort`. You should get a response from your app.

---

2 - `targetPort` indicates the service with which port connection should be established. Please refer to [define the service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service).

In `minikube` it may be confusing since it's pointed to the `service port`, not to the `targetPort` which is define within the service. I think idea was to indicate on which port `service` is accessible within the cluster.

---

3 - As for this question, there are headers presented, you can treat them literally. For instance:

```
$ kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE    SELECTOR
web-service   NodePort    10.106.206.158   <none>        80:30001/TCP   21m    app=web-pod
```

`NodePort` comes from your `web-service.yaml` for `service` object. `Type` is explicitly specified and therefore `NodePort` is allocated. If you don't specify `type` of service, it will be created as `ClusterIP` type and will be accessible only within kubernetes cluster. Please refer to [Publishing Services (ServiceTypes)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

When service is created with `ClusterIP` type, there won't be a `NodePort` in output. E.g.

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
web-service   ClusterIP   10.106.206.158   <none>        80/TCP    23m
```

`External-IP` will pop up when `LoadBalancer` service type is used. Additionally for `minikube` address will appear once you run `minikube tunnel` in a different shell. After your service will be accessible on your host machine by `External-IP` + `service port`.

---

4 - There are not issues with such mapping. Moreover this is a default behaviour for kubernetes:

> Note: A Service can map any incoming port to a targetPort. By default
> and for convenience, the targetPort is set to the same value as the
> port field.

Please refer to [define a service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service)

---

Edit:

Depending on the [driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) of `minikube` (usually this is a `virtual box` or `docker` - can be checked on linux VM in  `.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json`), `minikube` can have different port forwarding. E.g. I have a `minikube` based on `docker` driver and I can see some mappings:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
ebcbc898b557   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.23   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   5 days ago   Up 5 days   127.0.0.1:49157->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49156->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49155->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49154->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49153->32443/tcp   minikube
```

For instance 22 for ssh to ssh into `minikube VM`. This may be an answer why you got response from `http://127.0.0.1:52650/`

Comment: > There's no need to create pods separately
So I don't need a pod spec at all?

Comment: @Aaron in this exact case you have two yamls: `web-pod.yaml` and `web-deployment.yaml`. If you run `kubectl get pods` you will see three pods. 1 was created separately and 2 are managed by deployment.  `spec` for both of them is the same (image, port). You can safely delete separate pod by `kubectl delete -f web-pod.yaml` and then add this pod to deployment by scaling it up with `kubectl scale deploy web-deployment --replicas=3` - [Scaling a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#scaling-a-deployment)

Comment: You can read about [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) in official kubernets docs. It has use cases, some tasks to practice as well.

Comment: Yep removed the pod specs and it all worked the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this: "Reason why the application is not accessible on the localhost:NodePort is NodePort is exposed within VM where minikube is running, not on your local machine."

With dockerhost I can access via localhost:NODE_PORT. What does VM within minikube mean?

Comment: @Aaron This can take a whole new answer, but I'll try. You can treat this literally. Please read `edit` part in my answer. If you start minikube with `minikube start --driver=docker` (Ideally this is a default option, check `.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json`). After `minikube` started, run `docker ps -a` and you will see a giant container with minikube. Next step is `minikube ssh` to get ssh session into this VM and then run `docker ps -a` inside the minikube VM, you should see all kubernetes components.

Comment: Thanks so much! Great comment.

Comment: Awesome question and answers! However, I am unable to do the `curl ` command; it times out on the IP given by `minikube ip`. It only works when I  do `curl <tunnel url>`. Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?